# Tomcat uses high memory (RAM)

Tags: spring-boot, memory-management, java-8, tomcat8, tomcat9

My server system has 512 GB RAM. I installed two tomcat 8.5 and 9 with JAVA-8. Under the tomcat 9 only one Spring-Boot Rest API application runs and it uses only max 10 GB RAM.

The tomcat 8.5 runs one Spring MVC application and tomcat 8.5 used more then 150 GB RAM at a time and it is increasing time to time. I need re-start tomcat 8.5 in every 10-15 days. After restart the tomcat uses normal memory but after some time it increases.

What is the issue?

Comment: Are both tomcat servers running different applications? If so, it might be an issue of your application. Some memory leak perhaps?

Comment: Fix the memory leak. Monitor what happens in your application just stating that your memory goes up, without further investigation is not going to give you answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PiNaKa30 . I review of my all code, and I found no resource is leak even all resource is successfully closed after used. any other Idea..?

Comment: Looking at your code won't help. Add a profiler to your server and investigate, just inspecting the code won't help.